# how do I prove this trig inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, trigonometry

Prove that  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} > \arcsin(x)$ for when $0<x<1$.

What are the steps to solve this proof?
I tried to solve it like but it was not correct.

1/sqrt(1-x^2) -arcsinx > 0

x-arcsin*x*sqrt(1-x^2)/sqrt(1-x^2)>0

x-arcsin*x*sqrt(1-x^2) >0

x>arcsin*x*sqrt(1-x^2)

Comment: This is difficult to read.  For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Lele, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed because it is a very low-quality question. Moreover, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Comment: I've introduced some MathJax to your question. Please continue editing your question in order to have MathJax everywhere in the question for readability reasons.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fair chance this is not the optimal solution, but here we go:

Notice, since $0<x<1$, there exists some $0<y<\frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $\sin(y)=x$. Considering this substitution, we now get:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin(y)^{2}}} > \sin^{-1}(\sin(y))$

Which simplifies to:
$\frac{1}{\cos(y)} > y \implies \sec(y) > y$

Now, suppose for the sake of contradiction, $\sec(y) < y$. Then, it follows that
$\cos(y) >\frac{1}{y}$. Clearly, for $y<1$, this is absurd. So now consider $1\leq y < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Notice we know cossine and $\frac{1}{y}$ are decreasing in this interval. Further, at $y=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{1}{y} = \frac{2}{\pi} > \frac{3}{5}$. Meaning, since cossine is decreasing, $\frac{1}{y} > \frac{2}{\pi} > \frac{3}{5} > \cos\left(55^{\circ}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{18} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{36}\right) \geq \cos(y)$ for all $\frac{11\pi}{36} \leq y < \frac{\pi}{2}$ . Meaning, for $\frac{11\pi}{36} \leq y < \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $y<\frac{1}{\cos(y)}$.

So, we now have that our inequality holds for $0<y<1$ and $\frac{11\pi}{36} \leq y < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Since $\frac{11\pi}{36} < 1$, the union of these intervals gives that it holds for $0<y<\frac{\pi}{2}$, as desired.

Ps: the reason for choosing $\frac{3}{5}$ "out of nowhere" is the famous right triangle with sides 3,4,5 in which it is known the angles are roughly 53.(something) and 36.(something) degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=\sin y$ (which is invertible in $0<x<1$) so
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2y}}>y
$$
is to be shown for $0<y<\pi/2$.
$$
\frac{1}{\cos y}>y
$$
equivalent to
$$
1>y\cos y.
$$
[The sign of the inequality does not toggle because $\cos y>0$ in that region.]
This inequality is obviously valid at the ends of the interval, $y=0$ or $y=\pi/2$, where
the right hand side is zero.
The maximum of the right hand side is where the derivative is zero:
$$
(y\cos y)' = \cos y -y\sin y =0
$$
Solving for $y$, the maximum $y^m$ is at
$$
y^m\sin y^m =\cos y^m; \quad 1=y^m\tan y^m
$$
(which we don't compute explicitly, see https://oeis.org/A069855 ).
Because $\tan y> y$ in the interval $[0..\pi/2]$, we only need that $y^m< 1$ because otherwise $y^m\tan y^m>1$.
The value of the right hand side at
that maximum location is
$$
y^m\cos y^m = (y^m)^2\sin y^m.
$$
Because (see above) $y^m<1$ and $\sin y^m<1$, this product is $<1$, and because
$y\cos y$ is a continuous function with a single maximum, staying below 1 in the interval, the inequality is proved.